# Find required text box height if content and fontsize are known

Tags: xaml, windows-phone

I am building a **windows phone 8.1 app**.
I want to know if there is a way by which, given the **TextBox content** and **FontSize**, we can find out optimal height of the text box required before rendering the content on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any such algo to do that kind of calculation.But you can try something like below as test according to your app requirements

```
if (this.testButton.FontSize < 40)
            {
                this.testButton.Height = this.testButton.FontSize + 70;
            }
            else
            {
                this.testButton.Height = this.testButton.FontSize * 2;
            }
```